# TestDriven.net NCover problem

Tags: testdriven.net, ncover

I cannot run NCover. I get the error:

NCover couldn't create a coverage report

I'm running it via TestDriven.net. I am using MSTest and also have resharper 4.2 installed. There isnt a problem with the tests, as it works on collegues machines. Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an old version of NCover installed?  If you do, could you try uninstalling it. Could you also let me know which version you had installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had v3.3xxxx installed.